# What are harmonic function of $\mathbb R$?

Tags: real-analysis

What are harmonic function of $\mathbb R$ ? i.e. harmonic function $f:\mathbb R\longrightarrow \mathbb R$. Are they function s.t. $f''(x)=0$ for all $x$ ? i.e. function of the form $ax+b$ ?

Comment: Harmonic functions are defined on $\Bbb{R}^n$ only for $n>1$, see [here](http://www.axler.net/HFT.pdf).

Comment: @DietrichBurde : And function of $\mathbb R$ that has the mean value property has a special name ? (if such function exist).

Comment: @DietrichBurde: btw, in the paper you gave, they don't say why it can't be defined over $\mathbb R$, do they ?

Answer (score 0):

Harmonic functions in $\mathbb{R}$ are simply solutions of $\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}u = 0$. The only functions that satisfy this equation are linear functions $u(x) = ax + b$, where $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$.